# TFS Process Template - Creating Initial Version Control Folder Structure

Tags: version-control, tfs, tfs-process-template

I have searched and just can't seem to find the answer to this question so here goes...

I would like to edit a TFS Process Template to add the following folders to Version Control automatically when I create a new team project:

```
<teamProject>
  |- DEVELOPMENT
  |- MAIN
     |- BUILD
     |- SOURCE
     |- TEST
  |-RELEASES
```

Currently I have to add these folders for each new team project created. I'd like a little automation moving forward.

If the process template is not the place to accomplish, I suspect this can be done in the API, but so far unable to find the appropriate point to start.

Answer (score 0):

A really easy way to do this is to setup the folder structure the way you want in a Temp/Test Team Project and then when you create a new Team Project you will be given the option "Specify Source Control Settings"

[image]

In this dialogue, select "Create a new source control branch"  Branch from: Select the root of the Temp/Test Team Project.

In this way, all your future Team Projects will have the same structure as the Temp/Test Team Project.

Comment: Don't you worry about having "branches" which are meaningless? If you had a choice of "copy source control structure from `<path>`", then would you still want to use this "branch" choice?

Comment: It is in a temporary Team Project so it doesn't matter.  You can easily, with the new admin tools for 2010, delete a Team Project.  We have a SandBox project at our company along with many others for testing.  You can choose which Team Projects to view when you connect to the server. It is a very simple solution to the problem and what I would do if I were trying to solve this problem.  I understand what you are saying though but I really think if I just wanted to gen up 10 Team Projects this would work well.

Comment: Are you aware that branches now have special treatment in TFS 2010? I don't know if this will prove to be an actual "problem" in your case, but it is a difference from previous releases. This isn't just "branching in", like in VSS.

Comment: Two of our Main "Production" Team Projects were created similarly.  We are running without issue.

Comment: Good luck; hope it works; but make sure you know about [View Where and When Changesets Have Been Merged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd405662.aspx) and the other related new features of TFS 2010 to make sure they will work in this environment.

Answer (score 0):

I choose to create a custom solution (C#) who creates the TP programmatic and then creates a specific source control structure using the TFS Client Object Model.

Regards

Comment: Do you have a link to the code for this, or can give me some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Have not looked at this in detail, but http://mskold.blogspot.com/2010/10/tfs2010-automated-team-project-creation.html could give you some hints how you can achieve this.

There is also another post on StackOverflow that asked the same question: [TFS2010 Automatic folder structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897916/tfs2010-automatic-folder-structure)